# Security issues with iPhone installing drivers on Windows 10

Tags: windows, security, usb-flash-drive

When iPhone is plugged in computer running Windows 10 it starts installing drivers. Windows doesn't show UAC screen, or user permission to install drivers. Sure, it is convenient, but what is the security model here? Does it mean that any usb stick can silently gain permission for arbitrary code execution? Or this usb stick would needs a signed certificate to do so?

Comment: You can't compare an iPhone to a USB stick, really. It's like comparing your bank ATM card to your gym membership card.

Comment: So, what exactly is happening under the hood when I plug iphone in computer? What are the sufficient conditions for Windows to decide that code is legit?

Comment: @Tetsujin This is like saying. "A bunch of athletes broke in my house. Can anyone (like a random homeless guy) just get in my house? I didn't invite them" And you answer: "don't mix up cool athletes and some strangers!" I am glad, but it is my home or what? Same holds for Apple. They should bloody ask for permission to install stuff on MY computer.